# Denormalize sql database to import to Firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase, data-structures, database, nosql

I have a csv file with the following columns:

```
productID, 
SKU, 
productDescription, 
color, 
size1, size2, size3,...size30,  
price1, price2, price2,... price30, 
barcode1, barcode2, barcode3,... barcode30
```

Right now to search for a barcode in the database I use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName WHERE '0000042316060' 
IN (`barcode1`,`barcode2`,`barcode3`, ...`barcode30`)
```

How can I re-structure the database to import it to Firebase or other NoSql database and make the same query to get a product from a barcode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Node for each barcode and store the products under this node, e.g.:

```
--barcodes
    --0000042316060
        --productID1
            --productDescription1
    --0000042316061
        --productID2
            --productDescription2
    --0000042316062
        --productID1
            --productDescription1
```

Comment: One product have one productID and multiple Barcodes. So multiple barcodes share the same informations (sku, productID, descrition ecc...)

Comment: My answer is still valid: you will have  a same product under different barcodes -> you will be able, from one barcode, to get the product.

Comment: Yes but this is quite common in the NoSQL world. Like you say in your question title, you have to dernomalize. The storage is so cheap that it is not a problem to duplicate data in such a way it suits your needs for querying with the best possible performancE.

Comment: Didn't the OP state there was *one* product ID with multiple bar codes? Your answer is the opposite with *one* barcode and multiple product id's.

Comment: @Jay As I said, the answer was still valid in terms of philosophy (i.e. under a barcode node add the corresponding product). I've updated the tree to show that under a barcode goes only one product.

Answer (score 0):

I would just model the document as per the csv, and create an array for the size, price and barcode fields.  Like this:

```
{
  "productId" : 12345,
  "sku" : "sku-here",
  "productDescription" : "first product",
  "color" : "red",
  "size" : [1,2,3,4],
  "price" : [1.99, 2.50, 3.49],
  "barcode": ["0000042316060","0000042316061","0000042316062"]
}
```

This would require minimal reformatting of your source data, and allow you to run the queries to get the data you want using a query like this:

```
db.products.find({barcode:"0000042316060"})
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer - Firebase does not query like that and more importantly, Array's should generally be avoided in Firebase (or any NoSQL database). Also, the size and price arrays don't match element count.

Comment: mongodb does... which is what the question was tagged as

Comment: While it was added as a tag for reference, the question is about putting that database into Firebase. This answer states *allow you to run the queries to get the data you want using a query like this* but they are not running a mongoDB query - they are running queries against Firebase and Firebase doesn't support queries like that (hence the need to change the format & thought process of storing the data). Just trying to steer the OP in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since the product key is singular and there are multiple bar codes that go with each product key, here's a simple solution that links multiple bar codes so a single product.

```
products:
   product_id_0
      sku: "sku-here"
      productDescription: "first product"
      color: "red"

bar_codes
   0000042316060
      size: 1
      price: 1.99
      product_link: "product_id_0"
   0000042316061
      size: 2
      price: 2.50
      product_link: "product_id_0"
   0000042316062
      size: 2
      price: 3.49
      product_link: "product_id_0"
```

Your platform wasn't indicated but with this structure, if you know the specific bar code you can use observeSingleEvent (Swift) directly on the bar code to get it's information which will also provide the product_link back to the other product details, reducing the need to duplicate data.

```
let barCodeRef = self.ref.child("bar_codes").child("0000042316062")
barCodeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let barCodeDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let size = barCodeDict["size"] as! Int
    let price = barCodeDict["price"] as! String
    let productLink = barCodeDict["product_link"] as! String

    let productRef = self.ref.child("products").child(productLink)
    productRef.observeSingleEvent.....
        //get product info here
})
```

Additionally, if you know the product and want to see the options, you can query on the bar_codes node for that product_link which will retrive all of the bar codes, sizes etc.